# Python "int object is not callable"

Tags: python-3.x

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Anyone knows how can I fix this error? I know error is somewhere in the equation in the total. Thanks

```
decimal = 0 

rate = 0 

principal = 0 

years = 0

def simple(p, r, n,):

    decimal = r / 100
    print("Principal: " + str(p))
    print("Rate: " + str(decimal))
    print("Number of Years: " + str(n))

    total = p (1 + (decimal * n))
    print("Total: " + str(total))

def main():

    principal = int(input("Enter Principal: "))
    rate = float(input("Enter Rate: "))
    years = int(input("Enter Numbers of Years: "))

    simple(principal, rate, years)

main()

print("End of Program")
```

Comment: Since this is python code indenting it would be very helpful because wrong indentation can cause quite some unexpected problems!

Answer (score 1):

Here p is an integer that you try to call :

```
total = p (1 + (decimal * n))
```

I think that you want :

```
total = p*(1 + (decimal * n))
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line p is expected to be a function because it is immediately followed by a parenthesis:

```
total = p (1 + (decimal * n))
```

But p is passed as a parameter above, so I'm guessing you are passing an integer. If you mean to multiply:

```
total = p * (1 + (decimal * n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define p first `simple(int p,int r,int t)` then `total=p*(1+decim`