# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in np.random.seed

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to do data augmentation on 2018 Data Science Bowl previous competition on Kaggle. I am trying this code:

```
## Data augmentation
# Creating the training Image and Mask generator
image_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.5, rotation_range=50, zoom_range=0.2, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, fill_mode='reflect')
mask_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.5, rotation_range=50, zoom_range=0.2, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, fill_mode='reflect')

# Keep the same seed for image and mask generators so they fit together
image_datagen.fit(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)], augment=True, seed=42)
mask_datagen.fit(Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9)], augment=True, seed=42)

x=image_datagen.flow(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=42)
y=mask_datagen.flow(Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9)],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)



# Creating the validation Image and Mask generator
image_datagen_val = image.ImageDataGenerator()
mask_datagen_val = image.ImageDataGenerator()

image_datagen_val.fit(X_train[int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9):], augment=True, seed=seed)
mask_datagen_val.fit(Y_train[int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9):], augment=True, seed=seed)

x_val=image_datagen_val.flow(X_train[int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9):],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)
y_val=mask_datagen_val.flow(Y_train[int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9):],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True, seed=seed)
```

This is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-6b608552652e> in <module>
      5 
      6 # Keep the same seed for image and mask generators so they fit together
----> 7 image_datagen.fit(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)], augment=True, seed=42)
      8 mask_datagen.fit(Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9)], augment=True, seed=42)
      9 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py in fit(self, x, augment, rounds, seed)
    941 
    942         if seed is not None:
--> 943             np.random.seed(seed)
    944 
    945         x = np.copy(x)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The error as I understood is in the `seed` parameter in `image_datagen.fit`. The error message shows some internal problem in the `fit` code, as far as I'm concerned. I don't understand why.

I have explored other similar questions but I found none of them is suitable for my issue.

These are the solutions that I've read:

[Getting TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898510/getting-typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)

[Python "int object is not callable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915549/python-int-object-is-not-callable)

[class method TypeError "Int object not callable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723090/class-method-typeerror-int-object-not-callable)

Comment: Apparently you assigned something to `np.random.seed` at some point before this. Don't do that. That's not how you use `np.random.seed`.

Comment: I've had issues before with calculating a slice value to create the slice start:end before. If you use assign the stop point of the slice to a variable before calling do you get the same error?

Comment: @mgrollins , I face the same error still. user2357112 is right. Thank you both

Comment: At some point in your code, you did `np.random.seed = 10` (10 is just an example, could be any other number). Remove that line, restart your kernel and try again now with `np.random.seed(10)`

Comment: Thanks for the update @Noussa! Good luck!

Answer (score 19):

Make sure you **not** assign **np.random.seed** to some integer somewhere in your script

Like this:

```
np.random.seed = 42
```

Comment: Awesome! You must have done this and figured it out yourself after a long time!

Answer (score 4):

You have initialized the seed value like this:

```
np.random.seed = 42
```

instead try this:

```
np.random.seed(42)
```

and run the full code again